# Use jQuery to filter a find result from XML

Tags: jquery

I have an XML document that is a 2003 Spreadsheet XML document that I need to fetch data from. The trouble is that styling of cells means the XML will include rows that have no data, but styling applied. I need to return a list of just the rows that have data in the 10th cell of every row. How can I do this with jQuery?

XML Sample:

```
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Space">
  <Names>
   <NamedRange ss:Name="_FilterDatabase" ss:RefersTo="=Space!R1C1:R8C13"
    ss:Hidden="1"/>
  </Names>
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="13" ss:ExpandedRowCount="995" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s114" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="46.5">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="142.5"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="95.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="75.75"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="93"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="129"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="17.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="41.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:Width="236.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="135.75"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s116" ss:Width="51.75"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s116" ss:Width="53.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s116" ss:Width="18.75"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="63" ss:StyleID="s117">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell ss:Name="Space.Name"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">CreatedBy</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s88"><Data ss:Type="String">CreatedOn</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">Category</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">FloorName</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">Description</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"><Data ss:Type="String">ExtSystem</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"><Data ss:Type="String">ExtObject</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s86"><Data ss:Type="String">ExtIdentifier</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">RoomTag</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s112"><Data ss:Type="String">UsableHeight</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s112"><Data ss:Type="String">GrossArea</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s195"><Data ss:Type="String">NetArea</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s125"><Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell ss:Name="Space.Name"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s126"><Data ss:Type="String">.com</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s93"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2012-11-01T11:05:28.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s119"><Data ss:Type="String">Undefined</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s120"><Data ss:Type="String">01 Main Level</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s99"><Data ss:Type="String">GATHER</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s121"><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s121"><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s121"><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s122"><Data ss:Type="String">100 - Gathering Room</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s123"><Data ss:Type="Number">52</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s123"><Data ss:Type="Number">1674.1096940375501</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s124"><Data ss:Type="String">n/a</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Code that I have so far that will return all the rows, but not filtered for Cells with Data:

```
$(xml).find("Worksheet[ss\\:Name='Space'] Table Row")
```

I have tried applying a .filter at the end of the find, but I don't understand how a filter should be applied. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like:

```
$(xml).find("Worksheet[ss\\:Name='Space'] Row")
    .find('Cell:eq(9)').not(':empty').parent();
```

Where you go directly to the `Cell` elements, then remove the empty ones and return their respective `Row` parents.

Keep in mind in order to get the 10th `Cell`, you have to use `:eq(9)`, as you can see on [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

> Since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact. This is why $('.myclass:eq(1)') selects the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than the first.

Alternatively, you could use `:nth-child(10)` for the same result, which:

> Uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification.

Comment: That gets me really close, thank you! Is there a way to have it check one cell for the not empty condition? In this instance I need the 10th cell of every row to be checked.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that, I just changed the code accordingly

Comment: That's only returning the first row for some reason.

Comment: I'm with you on the 0-based indexing. For some reason I'm not understanding, it only returns one row though. I removed everything from ".not" on and it still only gives one record. I think that .children("Cell:eq(9)") is just returning the 10th cell, not the 10th cell of each row.

Comment: What about trying with `.find("Cell:eq(9)")` ?

Comment: $(xml).find("Worksheet[ss\\:Name='Space'] Row").find("Cell").eq(9) just gives one row still

Comment: Ok, I think i got it, I just made a test and doing it like `.find('Cell:eq(9)').not(':empty').parent()` should work...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19597/discussion-between-bishop-and-darkajax)